# adding div under header section creates weird ghost space and scroll bars on browser

Tags: css, html

whenever I add content underneath my header section weird ghost space appears and scroll bars appear on the browser window.

how can I get rid of this?

I've tried changing the width of the div.hours but nothing seems to work.

thanks

html:

```
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOURS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>  
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="imgs/sophies-white.png" alt="">
    </div>  
</header>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
</script>
```

css

```
/*  HEADER STYLING */

header {
    background-image: url(imgs/sophiesbg1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

nav {
    background-color: #fce0e6;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: calc(100vh - 58px)
 }

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica;
}


nav ul li {
    padding: 20px 15px;
}

header img {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

now for example if i add:

```
<div class="hours">
    <h1>hours</h1>
</div>
```

underneath the header in the body the ghost space appears.

before:[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9vgn.png)

after: [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhNt5.png)

Comment: What do you mean with _ghost space_? When having a look at the picture after you have made the addition I don't see any spurious space added.

Comment: nvm ive seemed to solve it by changing my 100vw to 100%

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal scrollbar appears because you use `width: 100vw;` in navigation and header. Replace it with `100%`, because otherwise, when a vertical scrollbar appears, it doesn't fit anymore.

For navigation you assume it's always 58px high, but this might vary on every browser. I suggest you make the header `position: relative;` and the navigation inside `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0`;

https://jsfiddle.net/v015rtmd/5/

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your vertical scrollbar, calc the height of the image:

```
header img {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

and adjust the margin-top of the nav section:

```
nav {
  background-color: #fce0e6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

and, get rid of the following in your header css:

```
height: 100vh;
```

You may need to keep playing with the '100px' value to get it exactly how you want it.

I was able to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar by adding margin:0 to the body style and getting rid of the width:100vw from the header css.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to body overflow:hidden; maybe can help you.

Comment: Did you verify that? If not, please construct a test case and see whether or not that is the case.